# CSS/HTML MENU: submenu disappearing on hover

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble with making the hover menu work. 
in the link below the submenu appears when I hover over the main menu item. When I try to hover over the submenu then it disappear when I move the cursor over it.

[A Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fru1e5no/6/)

**HTML**

```
<div id='menu'>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <center><a href="#">Services</a>
            </center>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Moving help ~ Deliveries</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Around the property</a>
                </li>
                <li> <a href="#"> Cleaning</a>
                </li>
                <li> <a href="#"> Minor Home Repairs</a> 
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"> Personal Care</a> 
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"> Skiller Handyperson</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <center> <a href='#'>company</a>
            </center>
            <ul>
                <li> <a href="about.php" class="firstli">About us </a>
                </li>
                <li> <a href="contact.php">Contact us </a>
                </li>
                <li> <a href="faq.php">F.A.Q. </a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="term.php">Terms of Use </a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="privacy.php" style="border-right:0px;">Privacy Policy </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#menu * {
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
    font: 12px georgia;
    list-style-type:none;
}
#menu {
    margin-top:300px;
    background-color:none;
    float: left;
    line-height: 10px;
}
#menu a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#menu a:hover {
}
#menu ul li ul li a:hover {
    padding-left:9px;
    border-left: solid 1px #000;
}
#menu ul {
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
#menu ul li ul li {
    width: 140px;
    border: none;
    color: #eee;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom:3px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    background:black;
}
#menu ul li ul li a {
    font: 11px arial;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    padding-top:3px;
    padding-bottom:3px;
}
#menu ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 146px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-top: solid 1px #283923;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #283923;
}
#menu ul li a {
    padding-left: 15px padding-right: 10px;
}
#menu li {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}
#menu ul li ul, #menu:hover ul li ul, #menu:hover ul li:hover ul li ul {
    display:none;
    list-style-type:none;
    width: 140px;
}
#menu:hover ul, #menu:hover ul li:hover ul, #menu:hover ul li:hover ul li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
#menu:hover ul li:hover ul li:hover ul {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -22px;
    font: 10px;
}
#menu:hover ul li:hover ul {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 1px;
    font: 10px;
    bottom:100%;
}
```

Comment: Put your code in your question please.

Comment: Of course this happens, because of the `margin-bottom:10px` you added to the absolutely positioned submenu `ul` … you need to make it so that there is no “space” in between the main menu item and the submenu, so that the mouse cursor can move from one to the other without any “breaks” in between, because that break makes the main menu item loose its hover state.

Comment: @CBroe exactly this is what I was looking for but could not find.. :) Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is your inner list has bottom margin, so it is separated from the parent `li` element:

[image]

If you want to keep the space, than you can use:

```
#menu ul {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

**[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/fru1e5no/11/)**

The result is no more gap in between and we do not lose `:hover` state:

[image]